# Search filter is too slow in angularjs with large dataset

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dirpagination

I have AngularJs client application which displays data in table using dir-paginate directive of dirPagination.js. here is the code

```
 <input type="text"  ng-change="SomeTask()"   ng-model="vm.searchKeyword" />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table" 
 id="indicatorsTable">
 <tbody style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
  <tr dir-paginate="user in vm.Results| filter: vm.searchKeyword:false  
  |orderBy:orderByField:vm.reverseSort| itemsPerPage:30"  current-
   page="vm.current_page"  ng-class-odd="'indicatorTableBgColor'">
    </tr>
    </table>
     <div  class="right col-lg-6">
                                            <dir-pagination-controls 
     style="float:right;" max-size="7" on-page-
     change="vm.onPageChange(this)" boundary-links="true"  template-
     url="./app/indicator/dirPagination.tpl.html">
                                            </dir-pagination-controls>
                                        </div>
```

Javascript controller function

```
 function GetDataFromBackEnd()
 {
    vm.Results=$http.GetData();
  }

 function SomeTask()
 {
   //do some task
  }
```

searching takes a lot of time as on every key input ng-change function is called. when I erase a name in the Search function and type in a new name there is a significant delay, like 20 seconds or so, for the system to catch up to my typing.

There is no change in performance even if I replace dir-paginate with ng-repeat.

SomeTask function computes pageindex for paging (like for showing 1 to 30 of 100 results). Even if we remove ng-change not sure where to compute the pageindex of the filtered result set.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you pre-fetch your data (even partially) and search from the stored array on `ng-change` ?

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: instead of loading your data with `$http` service or whatever every single time `ng-change` triggers, which is slow, you should load the data just once and then search from that pre-loaded data

Comment: Ok. But I do not load the data on ng-change but have a different task to do.I just use filter filter of angularjs to search

Comment: your filter must be optimised

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: show your code with filters

Comment: I have updated the question now. Included all the filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem using $filter service. I added $watch on search keyword and then searched for the keyword.

```
     $scope.$watch('vm.searchKeyword', function (term) {
        if (term != null && term != '') {             
            vm.Results = $filter('filter')(vm.orignalResults, term);
            }

     });
```